# accesing UI data from async taks

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to have an Activity that send the x,y coordinates clicked to a server in python. And I have problems updating the data of the async task from the UI thread.

Right now the activity gets the x,y coordinates ok, and I have a variable in the Activity of Class Client, that extends AsyncTask and connect to the server and send data.

Tried sending dummy data declared inside the doInBackground and all worked.

The problem start when I want the data of the asynctask to be updated by the UI thread. I tried to pass an ArrayList as parameter but when I try to pop (remove(0)) it say it doesnt regognize the command.

```java
public class mouse_activity extends AppCompatActivity {
 ArrayList<String> command_buffer;
 ...
 ...
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        client = new Client(ip,65432,client_show_text);
        client.execute(command_buffer);
   }
}
public class Client extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>, Void, Void>{
   @override
   protected Void doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... command_buffer) {
      ...
      String command = commands.remove(0);
```

When I try to remove(0) i get:
error: cannot find symbol method remove(int)

The expected result was to pop a command from that array that is shared so when you click on the screen it add one command to the command_buffer and in time the client will send them all in order.

Why is this? I feel like I'm trying to use the wrong tool, is there another way of doing that?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Please can somebody explain me why I get downvoted in every question? Is something I'm doing wrong? I followed the tutorial on how to ask and did extensive search before asking. I'm clueless on what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

First: the attribute `commands` is never declared, you are passing `command_buffer`.

Second: you can't update the UI from `doInBackground`, instead of it, do it in `onPostExecute`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer m8!
 - the name change was an error of mine while editing the question, is not in the code.
 - I don't want to update the UI, i want the thread, the doInBackground to get the new commands that the main UI is adding to the buffer.

Comment: Ok, just declare "command_buffer" as public static and change the name of the parameter in "doInBackground"

Comment: Thanks Sam! Finally I found the issue why I couldnt call the remove method. It was due to the "...".

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the issue.

```
  protected Void doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... command_buffer)
```

Those ... means that command_buffer is not an ArrayList, is a vector of those.

Thats why I couldnt call `command_buffer.remove(0).`

I realized it by trying to make a casting `((ArrayList<String>) command_buffer).remove(0)`, it didn't  work neither but it told me the type, so to solve it i made the following:

```
 protected Void doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... varArgs)
   ArrayList<String> command_buffer = varArgs[0];
```

And from there the code worked